# linkify multiple hashtags with no space using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag, linkify

I'm currently linkifying hashtags using regex like this:

```
var text = "#sun #summer";
text = text.replace(/(^|\s)#(\S+)/g, '$1<a href="/$2">#$2</a>');
```

output:

```
"#<a href="/sun">sun</a> #<a href="/summer">summer</a>"
```

this works fine, but sometimes people add hashtags without spaces in between them, so something like this: `"#sun#summer"`

how do I linkify this type of hashtags without spaces?

I tried this:

```
var text = "#sun#summer";
text = text.replace(/(^|.)#(.|\S+)/g, '$1<a href="/$2">#$2</a>');
```

output:

```
"<a href="/s">#s</a>un<a href="/s">#s</a>ummer"
```

but only works for one char after `#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var text = "#sun#summer";
text.replace(/#([^\s#]+)/g, '<a href="/$1">#$1</a>');
# => "<a href="/sun">#sun</a><a href="/summer">#summer</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, you could try the below regex,

```
(^|\b)#([^#]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eU3rG4/5)

Your code would be,

```
> var str = '#sun#summer';
> str.replace(/(^|\b)#([^#]+)/g, '$1<a href="/$2">#$2</a>');
'<a href="/sun">#sun</a><a href="/summer">#summer</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for `#sun#summer` but not when there are other words in the text for example: `hello #sun#summer sunny #hot`, @falsetru's answer worked for all

Comment: here is another test string: `hello #sun#summer sunny #hót #hot.hot, #hot_hot, #hot.`, can u help with this? `hot.hot` is valid, but `hot.` or `hot,` should only linkify `hot` , special char is also valid `hót`